# Converting Adapter onBindViewHolder itemView context to Class context with SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-context

I have a working recycle view:

```
public class MtbListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MtbListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList;
private ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayListFiltered;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public MtbListAdapter(ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
    this.arrayListFiltered =arrayList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_mtb, viewGroup, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position){

    //load texts to card
    recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.setText(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getName());
    recyclerViewHolder.tv_length.setText(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getLength());

    //is card already saved?
    String s_identifier = arrayListFiltered.get(position).getId();
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.getContext());
    boolean isSaved = databaseHelper.isSaved(s_identifier);

    if (isSaved) recyclerViewHolder.iv_isSaved.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else recyclerViewHolder.iv_isSaved.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` I check if the item is already saved and if so place a "saved" image on the card.  I do this by cheking an ID value against already saved items in my SQLite db.  One thing I'm concerned about is that `databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.getContext());` gets called a lot.  Question 1.  Is this a concern?

To alleviate my concerns, I tried passing context through the constructor and making databaseHelper a class Object, but whatever context I passed caused my SQLite database method to crash in the databaseHelper Class.  I tried passing Activity.this, application context, base context, etc.  I've only been successful passing the viewHolder item context as shown.  Like I said the code as written works, but I fear it is costly.

Here is the code I tried:

```
 public class MtbListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MtbListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList;
    private ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayListFiltered;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

public MtbListAdapter(ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
    this.arrayListFiltered =arrayList;
    this.context =context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_mtb, viewGroup, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position){

    //load texts to card
    recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.setText(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getName());
    recyclerViewHolder.tv_length.setText(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getLength());

    //is card already saved?
    String s_identifier = arrayListFiltered.get(position).getId();
    boolean isSaved = databaseHelper.isSaved(s_identifier);

    if (isSaved) recyclerViewHolder.iv_isSaved.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else recyclerViewHolder.iv_isSaved.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Here is my SQLite method:

```
 //returns true if is already saved
public boolean isSaved(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_IDENTIFIER};
    String where = KEY_IDENTIFIER + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {s};

    // select column_word from table where column_word = 's' limit 1;
    try (Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, "1")){
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

Here is my error (that I only get with the code posted that passes context through the contructor).  Otherwise it all works.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you please show the code you tried, and the error you got.

Comment: @cricket.... added.  Let me know if you need more error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the **context** via the constrcutor and then create an instance of the helper in the constructor.

e.g. Instead of :-

```
public MtbListAdapter(ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
    this.arrayListFiltered =arrayList;
}
```

use :-

```
public MtbListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ApiObject> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
    this.arrayListFiltered =arrayList;
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
```

and remove the line :-

```
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.getContext());
```

> One thing I'm concerned about is that databaseHelper = new
>   DatabaseHelper(recyclerViewHolder.tv_name.getContext()); gets called a
>   lot. Question 1. Is this a concern?

It's not the best way simply because you are re-constructing the instance. With regard to opening the database, that is actually done not at construction but when either `getReableDatabase` or `getWriteableDatabase` is called, which will be the same as that's done when the `isSaved` method is invoked. The get????ableDatabase are designed to cope with multiple invocations. So, I believe that there is little to be concerned about.

However, you don't close the Cursor in the `isSaved` method. This should be of concern as if you have too many Cursors open then an exception will occur.

You may want to change :-

```
//returns true if is already saved
public boolean isSaved(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_IDENTIFIER};
    String where = KEY_IDENTIFIER + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {s};

    // select column_word from table where column_word = 's' limit 1;
    try (Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, "1")){
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

to something like :-

```
//returns true if is already saved
public boolean isSaved(String s) {
    boolean rv = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_IDENTIFIER};
    String where = KEY_IDENTIFIER + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {s};

    // select column_word from table where column_word = 's' limit 1;
    (Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, "1"));
    if(c.moveToFirst) {
            rv = true;
    }
    c.close()
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  Please see question again.  Thanks!

Comment: Then you are likely passing null to the adapter.  Perhaps add something like `if (context == null) { Log.d("MTBLISTADPTR","Null passed to constructor"); }`. Additionally, in the `isSaved` method. P.S. you may well encounter issues if you don't close the cursor. Something like 100's times and you'll get too many DB's open exception (can't recall the exact message error off-hand).

Comment: Just looked more closely at the new code you added. You create the instance of the database helper as a class variable. That will not work. You need to instantiate `databaseHelper` in the constructor. In the class just declare databaseHelper i.e. `private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;`, then instantiate in the constructor using `databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);`

Comment: Such a great answer.  Clear and spot on.  I wish I could click it up 10 times.  Thank You!